# Up and Down Arrows Aren't Working with onkeydown in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm building a simple obstacle game and the problem I'm having right now is that I can use the arrow keys to move left and right, but not up and down. I don't get why up and down don't work when they have the same logic as left and right. I'm fairly new to developing things on my own so go easy on me if it's obvious. :)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Grab the elements from the HTML
  const floppy = document.getElementById("floppyDisk");
  const gameBoard = document.querySelector(".gameBoard");

  let userScore = document.getElementById("userScore");
  let highscore = document.getElementById("highscore");

  // Set up variables to be used later
  let floppyPosX = 0;
  let floppyPosY = 0;
  let left = 20;
  let top = 190;

  // Use the arrows to move the floppy disk
  function moveFloppy(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
      left += 2;
      floppy.style.left = floppyPosX + left + "px";
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      left -= 2;
      floppy.style.left = floppyPosX + left + "px";
    }
    if(e.keycode == 38) {
      top += 2;
      floppy.style.top = floppyPosY + top + "px";
    }
    if(e.keycode == 40) {
      top -= 2;
      floppy.style.top = floppyPosY + top + "px";
    }
  }

  // Invoke the moveFloppy function
  document.onkeydown = moveFloppy;
  
  // Generate Obstacles
  
    // Function to move the obstacles

    // Set function to repeat


  // Call the function to generate the obstacles

})
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use `document.onkeydown`, use `document.addEventListener( 'keydown', moveFloppy )`.

Comment: Also, consider using `switch` instead of a load of `if` statements.

Comment: Can you post the HTML & CSS as well? In fact you could convert into a runnable snippet of code. I suspect if you check the styles of that element in the DOM inspector you'll see the `top` style is changing but the `position` in conjunction with the container makes it such where the element isn't moving.

Comment: Oops, it's just a typo. For left/right, you're using `e.keyCode`. For up/down you're using `e.keycode`. If that's also in your actual code, you should just be able to fix by using the proper event property name in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you're using [the **deprecated** (and ill-defined) `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) instead of the standardised `code` property.

Change your JavaScript to this and it should work:

- Disclaimers:

  - I haven't assessed the correctness of your `left`/`floppyPosX` logic.
  - I changed your `if` statements to a single `switch` statement.

    - Be careful with `switch` [as it has fallthrough unless you use `break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```
function moveFloppy(e) {
    switch(e.code) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
        left += 2;
        floppy.style.left = floppyPosX + left + "px";
        break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
        left -= 2;
        floppy.style.left = floppyPosX + left + "px";
        break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
        top += 2;
        floppy.style.top = floppyPosY + top+ "px";
        break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
        top -= 2;
        floppy.style.top = floppyPosY + top + "px";
        break;
    default:
        // TODO: Play a fart sound.
        break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener( 'keydown', moveFloppy );
```

Comment: This is an improvement, but it's not why the original code didn't work.

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, my mistake - I assumed it was because they were using a browser or computer with non-standard `keyCode` values.